# Fastest search in lines of string

Tags: javascript

I have data lines (first line is headers, the rest lines are the data) passed as a single argument my function:

```
"id,first,last,email\n" + 
"555,John,Doe,jd@gmail.com\n" + 
"666,Jason,scott,js@gmail.com\n" + 
.......
```

I would like to search in those lines for an email value. In case I found it, I should return the complete line.
So i only need to look for 4th element in each row.

I was thinking about something like that:

```
function search(data, key) {  
var arr = text.split('\n'); /// convert data to array

return function (value) {
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var dataLine = arr[i].split(','); /// "666,Jason,scott,js@gmail.com\n" to array
            if (dataLine[keyIndex] === value) { /// found match between value and id
                return "found";
            }
        }
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

What would be the the fastest way to search?

Does the conversion of each row to array in each loop iteration is considered a waste?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the data ahead of time, or using the same data always, you can parse it into a 2d array before you call your search function to speed it up. This is just one optimization.

Comment: If you want to trade-off memory for speed, something like `var table = { 'email@email.com' : { fullRow: '555,John,Doe...' } }` so then you can just test `if (table[search])` for a O(1) lookup. This table would have to be generated when you read the data in.

Comment: there's no need to reinvent the wheel, you could simply use `String.prototype.indexOf(substr)` if you have it in string format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: `arr.filter(/./.test, /jd@gmail\.com/)[0]`

Comment: -Glen, after pulling the index (e.g 20), how can I extract the complete line?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to look at the *last* element in each `arr` item. So, the inner function can be sped up by avoiding the `split()` call:

```
function(value) {  
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    if (item.substr(item.lastIndexOf(',')+1) === value) {
      return "found";
    }
  }
  return "not found";
}
```

*By the way, the for loop starts `i` at 1 to ignore the headers.*

Comment: I started the loop from 1, bcz the first line of data represents the headers of the data: "id,first,last,email\n"

Comment: OK. Probably should have stated that in the question. I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to construct regexp like this `/^([^,]*,){3}searched@mail.xyz(,.*)?$/gi` and run the match method of the input string with this regex as parameter.

```
var fieldsBefore=keyIndex?"^([^,]*,){"+keyIndex+"}":"^"
var fieldsAfter="(,.*)?$"
var rx=new RegExp(fieldsBefore+searched+fieldsAfter,"g")
var result=input.match(rx)
if(result){//lines found
...
}
else{//not found
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following dandavis advise I modified the function to:

```
function search(data, key) {
    var arr = text.split('\n'); /// convert data to array

    return function (value) {
        var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID, value);
        console.log(arrByID); /// -> ["555,John,Doe,jd@gmail.com"]
    }
}

function filterByID(stringLine) {
    if (stringLine.indexOf(this) > -1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for great ideas!